# Predict_classes() keras model ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer:

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, predict

Okay I'm new to this I'm trying to classify Traffic Sign images Im actually  following a notebook from Kaggle, after building the Keras model

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(43, activation='softmax'))

#Compilation of the model
model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
    optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

now for the test part after fitting the model the code i found is like this

```
y_test=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Louay/input/test.csv")
labels=y_test['Path'].to_numpy()
y_test=y_test['ClassId'].values

data=[]

for f in labels:
    image=cv2.imread('C:/Users/Louay/input/Test/'+f.replace('Test/', ''))
    image_from_array = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
    size_image = image_from_array.resize((height, width))
    data.append(np.array(size_image))

X_test=np.array(data)
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')/255 
pred = model.predict_classes(X_test)
```

this works and it predicts the classes of all images in the test set correctly my problem is when I tried to predict only 1 image from the test set okay I thought I would repeat the same image processing part and then use `predict_classes()` so my code should be like this

```
image=cv2.imread('C:/Users/Louay/input/Test/00000.png')
image_from_array = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')
size_image = image_from_array.resize((height, width))
test=np.array(size_image)

pred = model.predict_classes(test.astype('float32')/255)
```

okay I'm working on 1 image so I thought I don't need the `data[]` list where I append all processed images but when I run the code I get this error

```
   ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, None, 3]
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but before correcting my code I really want to understand why am I getting this error what's causing it, what's actually happening?

Comment: Does it work better if you do `test=np.array([size_image])` so the single image is inside a list when you convert it to array?  That seems more like what was happening when you had multiple test images.  If that works, you can look at the two different versions of test (with and without []) to see how the array is different.

Comment: wait i just tried ```test=np.array(size_image)``` and then ```test=np.array([test])``` and it worked for me but why ? i mean it looks like im doing ```np.array``` on a list of ```np.array``` can anyone explain to me please what actually ```predict_classes()``` takes as parameter ?

Comment: Try `type(size_image)` to see what it is.  Other methods to try might be `test.shape`, `test.size`, `len(test)`.  Also `help(model.predict_classes)`.

Comment: Try tf.expand_dims to add a dimension to your single image. 
example : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims

Answer (score 0):

Conv2D expects 4+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols)` if data_format='channels_first' or 4+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (rows, cols, channels)` if data_format='channels_last'.

Add extra dimension to your input using `tf.expand_dims`

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf

image = tf.zeros([10,10,3])
input_shape = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0).shape.as_list()

x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)
print(y.shape)
```

Output

```
(1, 8, 8, 2)
```